# Add site specific hashtag to Twitter feeds

Tags: feature-request, twitter

Stack Exchange sites have nifty Twitter accounts, eg [@StackMath](https://twitter.com/StackMath) and [@StackWordpress](https://twitter.com/StackWordpress) where upvoted questions get a tweet.

The tweet contains the post title, a link to the question, and a hashtag based on the most popular tag on the question.

The accounts, and therefore the questions, would get better exposure if there was an additional site specific hashtag.  For example, more people would see the @StackWordpress tweets if they also included the [#WordPress](https://twitter.com/search?src=typd&q=#WordPress) hashtag, which would probably lead to community growth.

This wouldn't make sense for all sites (eg, I doubt SO would benefit from it), but I think that many (most?) of the the 2.0 sites benefit from this.

So, I am requesting that site communities get to

- vote (via their Metas) on whether they want a specific hashtag
- vote for what that hashtag should be

Comment: Great idea. I wonder what the Meta community would vote its hashtag to be? :)

Comment: @BilltheLizard #unicornpoo

Comment: [copy of bounty text] Should not be too hard to implement, and would increase the visibility of these accounts. I don't see any downsides: the tweeted questions don't look like spam, and their frequency is reasonable. Same request on per-site metas: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/1834 and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/16733/

Comment: #hashtag, of course.

Answer (score 12):

Nobody is stopping individual sites from voting on hashtags to include. :) There's even a precedent with Project Management and the #pmot hashtag. *However*, y'all gotta keep in mind the maximum tweet length. Can't go too crazy with hashtags when there's title summary and URL to get in there as well.

As with a lot of site-specific features... there's not much development work to be done here until there's a proven need. Y'all gotta start with a meta discussion to see if your community even supports this initiative and/or thinks the Twitter posts are useful. If there's a tangible upside to this, we'll find a way to make it work.

In all fairness, I should note that we haven't noticed much benefit from automatic tweeting on our end *and* Twitter is starting to come after site-specific profiles we used to make because they appear too automatic to them. Setting that side for a moment... go ahead, start your meta discussions. We monitor per-site metas and can set up hashtags for the sites that most want them to see if that makes any practical difference.

Comment: http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/q/3088

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/16733/

Comment: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1834/get-our-stacktravel-account-to-use-travel-in-the-tweets